# gmock failed to pass values to my function

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am using gmock in my project and I meet a problem to set a custom reference variable for a mock function. I have used SetArgPointee and Return ,but the function can only get the return value.

my mock function is

```
MOCK_METHOD1_WITH_CALLTYPE(__stdcall, get_length, HRESULT(long *p));
```

my TEST is like this:

```
long pl = 10;    
EXPECT_CALL(*ihtmlelemc, get_length(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<0>(pl), Return(S_OK)));
```

in my test function is

```
long len = 0;
HRESULT hr;

hr = pObjCollect->get_length(&len);
if (hr != S_OK || len == 0)
{
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

when I run the test only found that thr hr is S_OK, len is still 0, the len can't get the value,anyone can tell me why and how to get the value,thanks.

Comment: ,I get the value by using ACTION_P like this *arg0 = value and return S_OK, I think I have used a wrong type.